# What's the difference between 상태동사 and 형용사?

Tags: grammar

[Korean Grammar for International Learners](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8971415541) calls descriptive verbs 상태동사:

[image]

However, I thought these words were also often called 형용사 - so I got the impression that 상태동사 and 형용사 are basically the same thing. Following a conversation with another Korean SE friend here, I wonder if that is correct.

Are 상태동사 and 형용사 the same thing, are 형용사 a subset of 상태동사, or are they different altogether?

Comment: Status verbs and adjectives are totally different things!

Comment: Plus, 강하다 and 밝다 should both be adjectives.

Comment: I've never heard "상태동사" while learning Korean as a native speaker.

Comment: @choco_addicted It does seem that a web search for "상태동사" mainly brings up sites talking about English, so as Rathony says, maybe this is an editorial oddity.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 상태동사 in Korean. I think you are confused with other languages such as English. There are only verbs and adjectives in Korean and nothing in-between.

The simplest way to distinguish 형용사 (adjective) from 동사 (verb) is to conjugate by **placing '-ㄴ' or '-는' before '다'** using the basic (root) form. If the conjugated form makes sense, it is a verb. If not, it is an adjective as follows:

1. Changing the words to basic forms.

> 슬프네 -> 슬프다
>
> 예뻤지 -> 예쁘다
>
> 먹어라 -> 먹다
>
> 가신다 -> 가다

2. Place '-ㄴ' (when the last word before 다 ends with a vowel) or '-는' (when it ends with a consonant) before '다'.

> 슬프다 -> 슬**픈**다 (X)
>
> 예쁘다 -> 예**쁜**다 (X)
>
> 먹다 -> 먹**는**다 (O)
>
> 가다 -> 간**다** (O)

The first two are adjectives and the last two are verbs.

Let's see how your examples work.

> 강하다 -> 강**한**다 (X)
>
> 밝다 -> 밝**는**다 (X)

Neither of them works and it proves that they are adjectives.

When you see a translated version of those adjectives in Korean, it might sound like a verb, but there is no 상태동사 in Korean.

Comment: question updated.

Comment: @topomorto There is nothing to add based on your edit. The book is wrong and not worth my attention.

Comment: If there is no 상태동사 then how do yiu explain why 앉아있다 is right while 앉고 있다 wrong? Exactly because 앉는다 is status verb, isn't it? 먹고 있다, 가고 있다 are all acceptable but not 앉고 있다!

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy What makes you think 앉아있다 is 상태동사? Is "sitting" in "He is sitting at the table" a 상태동사? There is no such word as "앉는다". "앉다" is the root form of '앉아있다'.

Comment: Sit is status verb since you can be either sitting or nit sitting, you cannot have continuous state

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy Hmm... I don't think you understand what stative verbs in English are and how they work. 1. Mental and emotional states (Believe, doubt, feel (opine), imagine, know, like, love), 2. Senses (appear, hear, look (seem), see), 3. Reactions ((dis)agree, deny, impress, mean), 4. Description, possessions, etc. (Be, belong, concern, consist, contain, depend, deserve, fit, include, own, possess). Sit is not a stative verb in English.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this. Indeed, English is not my mother tone

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy How you call a word or phrase is not critical. The most important thing in learning language is understand how they work and when to use them.

Comment: Yeah, the types of words, I have no such concept when learning English.

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy You can join English Language and Usage and ask questions there.

Comment: @Rathony thanks for having another look. The book may well be  unconventional in its terminology, and a bit of web searching suggests that may be the case too, though a native Korean speaker I asked was also quite happy with the idea that 강하다 is a 상태동사... maybe it's just that no-one quite agrees!

Comment: @topomorto How many native English speakers do you think are familiar with grammatical part of speech and grammatical functions of words? When you describe something as "strong", you are describing its attribute (characteristic) and nothing moves. It is not healthy to overthink a part of speech as it is complicated and confusing.

Comment: @Rathony Of course one doesn't take a single native speaker's ideas as gospel - it's just another bit of 'evidence'. I agree that defining words isn't very exciting, but it does help avoid polluting more potentially interesting conversations with misunderstandings.

Comment: Stative verbs do exist in Korean.

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=36788)

1) There are several ways in defining a descriptive verb.

2) Descriptive verb and dynamic verb are subsets of verb and
adjective is a subset of descriptive verb. But it is mechanical view
point. In language view point, we use term adjective.